# jquery typeof() returns every input value as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery typeof() returns every input value as a string? how do i get number type?

```js
var c = $('#inputbox').val();
$('#show').on('click',function(){
console.log(typeof(c));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result" >inputbox type</p>
<input type="text" id="inputbox" />
<button id="show">show</button>
```

Comment: what do you expect? `val()` will return _string_ literal

Comment: If you're expecting _integer_ for numbers, then use parseInt(value). So `typeof(parseInt(c))`

Comment: try this isNaN(c)

Comment: @Satpal what should i do ? if i want to find the entered value a string or number?

Comment: if user enters a number it should return number , if user enters a string it should return string type ( for validation purpose)

Comment: Or just use [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) since you are already using jQuery and don't make own validation implementation.

Comment: `typeof` is a keyword, not a function (you shouldn't use it with parenthesis), and it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following with `isNaN()` and `parseInt()`:

```js
$('#show').on('click',function(){
  var c = isNaN(parseInt($('#inputbox').val())) ? $('#inputbox').val() : parseInt($('#inputbox').val());
  console.log(typeof(c));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result" >inputbox type</p>
<input type="text" id="inputbox" />
<button id="show">show</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `isNaN` to check if a string is of a valid number or not. Like this:

```js
var str = "67klk";

if(isNaN(str))
  console.log(str + " is not a number!");
else
  console.log(str + " is a number!");


str = "67.75";

if(isNaN(str))
  console.log(str + " is not a number!");
else
  console.log(str + " is a number!");
```